# Theorem Hahn–Banach

Tags: functional-analysis

Let X be a normed space and $ S (x_0; r) \subset X $ center sphere $x_0$ and radius $r$: Show that
given $x_1 \in S (x_0; r)$ there is hyperplane $H$ satisfying $x_1 \in H$ and closed ball $\overline{B}
(x_0; r)$ is entirely contained in one of the semi-spaces determined by H.

For $ x_0 = 0$, I used the Hahn–Banach theorem as an extension, and ok!

I'm having a hard time for $ x_0 \neq 0 $, I think I have to use Hahn–Banach convex separation, any help?

Answer (score 3):

Just translate everything so $x_0$ becomes $0$, and use your result for $x_0=0$.

Comment: I even considered this, but I wondered if I could generalize this fact. thank you